# How to Shift the Order of Elements within a <div>?

Tags: javascript, html

### My Problem:

Hey everybody. I have a quick question in regards to changing the order of elements in **HTML** using **JavaScript**. I want the items in the list to shift their positions down every time a button is clicked.

For example, the elements start in this order:

```
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
```

When the button is clicked they should shift to this order:

```
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
```

### What I've Tried:

I've written all of the code up until the part where it changes the order of the elements. I'm just not sure what function or method to use, so I don't even know where to start when it comes to trying to accomplish what I want to happen.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.

### My Code:

```js
var itemList = document.getElementsByClassName('item-list')
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item')
var shiftBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('shift-btn')

for (let i = 0; i < shiftBtns.length; i++) {
    shiftBtns[i].addEventListener('click', shiftItems)
}

function shiftItems(event) {

    // Insert code that shifts the elements here.
    console.log('Wow! The order has changed!')
    
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class="shift-btn">Shift Items</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement), with `afterbegin` in this example:

```js
var itemList = document.getElementsByClassName('item-list')
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item')
var shiftBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('shift-btn')

for (let i = 0; i < shiftBtns.length; i++) {
  shiftBtns[i].addEventListener('click', shiftItems)
}

function shiftItems(event) {
  itemList[0].insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", items[items.length - 1]);
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class="shift-btn">Shift Items</button>
```

The tricks applied are that APIs inserting nodes/elements remove the given node/element from its old place, and the `getElementsBy...()` methods often produce a live `NodeList`, which follows changes of the original collection. That's how the last element in the single `items` collection automatically changes here and `items[items.length - 1]` refers to a different element after each click.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the last item using [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild)
2. Add it to the beginning using [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
3. Remove it using [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

---

```js
function shiftItems(event) {
    const last = itemList[0].lastElementChild;
    itemList[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', last.outerHTML);
    last.remove();
}
```

---

```js
var shiftBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('shift-btn');
var itemList = document.getElementsByClassName('item-list');

for (let i = 0; i < shiftBtns.length; i++) {
    shiftBtns[i].addEventListener('click', shiftItems)
}

function shiftItems(event) {
    const last = itemList[0].lastElementChild;
    itemList[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', last.outerHTML);
    last.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class="shift-btn">Shift Items</button>
```

Comment: This could potentially work, however, after the first item is moved up all of the elements following it are placed underneath the prior element, as opposed to on top of it. It also does not loop once Item 1 reaches the end of the list.

Comment: The last element is always moved to the top. My first answer had a mistake, do you still see this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shift function using [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild), [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) and [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

```js
function shift() {
    const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('item-list')[0];
    const last = parent.lastElementChild;
    parent.removeChild(last);
    parent.insertBefore(last, parent.firstElementChild);
}

const shiftButton = document.getElementsByClassName('shift-btn')[0];
shiftButton.onclick = shift;
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class="shift-btn">Shift Items</button>
```